# How do you programatically open multiple rows in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I thought this question would have been answered but I can't work this out. Have tried:

- https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25833/is-there-any-way-to-programmatically-select-rows
- https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().select()

I'm using DataTables 1.10.16 in `serverSide` mode - my data is loaded in via ajax as opposed to being there on page load.

My markup is simply a table with an ID, `#substancesTable`:

```
<table id="substancesTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>EC</th>
            <th>CAS</th>
            <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

The js to load the data is as follows:

```
var substancesTable = $('#substancesTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/get-substances.json",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
             return json.data;
        }
    }
});
```

This populates my table fine. I have an event handler such that when a user manually clicks on on a row (any `<td>` element inside the `#substancesTable`) it makes a further ajax request to obtain more data which is then populated inside the `<td>` that the user clicked. This code is also responsible for closing/collapsing any open rows:

```
$('#substancesTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = substancesTable.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        row.child( expand_substance(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

The code above calls a function `expand_substance` which handles the ajax request mentioned. This all works fine.

What I'm trying to do is find a way to programatically open certain rows. What I mean by this is having an array of row ID's that the user has clicked on, e.g.

```
var openRows = [5, 6, 8, 33, 100];
```

This array data will be stored in Redis (cache) so if the user navigates away from the page, when they return, the data in `openRows` will be loaded and I want to open the appropriate rows. But I don't know how to tell DataTables to open rows 5, 6, 8, 33, 100, etc.

The links above don't seem to work for me. For example, if I try:

```
substancesTable.row(':eq(0)', { page: 'current' }).select();
```

I get a console error:

> `VM308:1 Uncaught TypeError: substancesTable.row is not a function`

I'm not sure if that's even how to open the row but couldn't find any more information that helped.

So, is it possible to use JavaScript to open certain rows of the table based on an array of known ID's (`openRows`)?

Comment: You could possible just do something like `openRows.each(function({ $(this).show()});` ?

Comment: I am not sure at what point you are trying to call row() but it does not look like it is a reference to the DataTable API at that point based on the error.  Possibly substancesTable  is getting reassigned to something else at before calling row().  You can get a reference to an already initialized DT by calling $("#substancesTable").DataTable() again with no options passed.

Comment: @PaulZepernick thanks. I was using it in the console after the page had been rendered. I tried using `$("#substancesTable").DataTable().row(':eq(o)', {page: 'current'}).select();` but it errors with - "VM967:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).row(...).select is not a function"

Comment: There is no select() method off the row object returned in the api doc:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/
you can do row(..).child().show() or row(..).child().hide()

Comment: I just noticed you put the link to the doc... The select() method is apparently some DataTable extension that is not there by default.  I am not familiar with it, but my guess is that the extension is not loaded.  This is at the top of the doc in the link provided "Please note - this property requires the Select extension for DataTables."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was provided by a colleague and makes use of the `rowCallback` (https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) callback which DataTables provides.

```
var substancesTable = $('#substancesTable').DataTable({

// ...

"rowCallback": function(row) {
       var id = $(row).find('td:first').text();
       var index = $.inArray(id, openRows);

       if (index !== -1) {
           var tr = $(row).closest('tr');
           var row = substancesTable.row( tr );
           row.child( expand_substance(row.data()) ).show();
           tr.addClass('active');
       }
    }
});
```

This callback will post process each row (represented by `row`). The line `var index = $.inArray(id, openRows);` means is the current row (identified by the text from `var id`) in the array of `openRows`. Since the first column in my table contains the ID that's how we can get a match between `var id` and `openRows`.

If the ID is found it will then trigger a function I've written called `expand_substance()`. This is nothing to do with DataTables, it's a custom js function.

In my case the `expand_substance()` function is responsible for doing an ajax call to obtain some more details which are then populated into the row:

```
function expand_substance ( rowData ) {
    var div = $('<div/>')
        .text('Loading...');

    $.ajax( {
        url: '/view-substance/expand-substance/' + rowData.id,

        dataType: 'html',
        success: function ( data ) {
            div.html(data);
        }
    });

    return div;
}
```

This is only required because when the user expands a row in my application the details which are shown are obtained via an ajax request. In theory `expand_substance()` might not be used if the data was there on page load.

This works in my application. The other Answer provided to this post is along the right lines but does not use ajax source data, and it does not expand a row, but instead just highlights it in red. Therefore I've provided my own answer because this fully addresses the question and others may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

That one was fun to resolve (*hoping I did*)... since it is quite complicated and tricky.

First, I have to mention that it's not possible (or at least a pain) to build a demo using the server side feature, so I used DataTable's ["zero configuration" example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html).

Now, I hope I correctly understand that a row index array is to be previously stored from user row clicks... And that it's the starting point of the current question to reuse that array to manipulate the rows.

In my example, there are only 57 rows... So I used this array: `var targets = [5, 6, 8, 33]`.

The solution step by step:

1. Use the [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to run a for loop on the array.
2. Get the drawn rows in the right order... Which means **after** sort.
   We need to use the [row-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) along with the useful `{ order: 'applied' }` trick.
   (*Found in a [dataTables forum question](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26760/get-row-number-in-display-order-after-sort)*)
3. Get the [`nodes`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().node()) from it.
4. Target the right rows, based on the array, using the jQuery [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.
   So we have to create a jQuery object with the row collection first (wrap with `$()`).
5. Manipulate the rows!
   In my example, I just added a red background color to the child `td`.
   You will do your things from here.

So here is the whole function:

```
"drawCallback": function(){
  var api = this.api();

  for(i=0;i<targets.length;i++){
    $(api.rows({ order: 'applied' }).nodes()).eq(targets[i]).find("td").addClass("red");
    console.log(targets[i]);
  }
}
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zMGEPq?editors=1111)

---

**Remember** that rows are zero-based...
**Notice** that the row indexes manipulated above are **after** sort (so it reflects the order as currently displayed to user, not the order as supplied to Datatables from the markup or from Ajax.) **That means** the sorting shall be the same as when the user clicked the rows (thus saved the indexes). That *may* be a problem... ;)

Comment: This is good and is definitely along the right lines as you've managed to target rows based on an array. Your assumption about the array being "previously stored from user row clicks." is correct. However... I want to be able to *open* the rows. I tried modifying your code so that it has `.addClass("red").open()` (note the `.open()` at the end) but this doesn't seem to do anything, the rows remain red but they do not expand.

Comment: In my zero configuration example, there is nothing to "open". The example is about how to target the rows only. In your own DataTable, try `$(api.rows({ order: 'applied' }).nodes()).eq(targets[i]).addClass("shown red").child().show();`. If that works well as it should, just remove the red class from that line (just for testing) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've written up my own answer which works in my application. It's important that the answer takes into account using ajax source data and also expands the row as opposed to merely highlighting it. Your answer was along the right lines though.